# Remove rows after first occurrence of a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following df:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                 var2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"))
```

I want to filter after the moment the first 5 (var1) is reached. 
So the result should be:

```
  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    2    c
4    3    d
5    4    e
6    5    f
```

I tried:

```
   df1 <- df %>%
     mutate(a = !duplicated(var1)) %>%
     filter(var1 < 6 & a == TRUE)
```

But the problem here is that is also deletes the duplicates the var2(c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` to create a logical `vector`

```
df %>% 
  filter(cumsum(var1 == 5) < 2)
#    var1 var2
#1    1    a
#2    2    b
#3    2    c
#4    3    d
#5    4    e
#6    5    f
```

---

Or another option is `slice` with `match`

```
df %>%
   slice(seq(match(5, var1)))
```

---

Or with `which.max` (assuming there is a 5 value)

```
df %>%
   slice(seq(which.max(var1 == 5)))
```

Comment: If the there is no 5 value in var1, then the third option can be edited to: `df %>% filter(var1 <= 5) %>% slice(seq(which.max(var1)))`