# Filter up to observing first specific value

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to filter only the first type=="y" value observed.

```r
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
type=c("x","x","y","x","x","x","x","y","y","x","x","x","x","y","x","y","x","x"))
```

Desired output:

```
 id type
   1    x
   1    x
   1    y
   2    x
   2    x
   2    x
   2    y
   3    x
   3    x
   3    x
   3    x
   3    y
```

I try it with the code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(type == "x"|sum(type == "y") == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Same but on ungrouped data: [Remove rows after first occurrence of a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803281/remove-rows-after-first-occurrence-of-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take help of `match` and use it in `slice` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(1:match('y', type)) %>% ungroup

#     id type 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 x    
# 2     1 x    
# 3     1 y    
# 4     2 x    
# 5     2 x    
# 6     2 x    
# 7     2 y    
# 8     3 x    
# 9     3 x    
#10     3 x    
#11     3 x    
#12     3 y
```

`match` would return the position of first `'y'` in each group. This however, would fail if there are no `'y'` in `type` column for a `id`. If that is the case then you can use `filter` like below which would return all the rows for the group if there is no `'y'` in it.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(lag(cumsum(type == 'y'), default = 0) < 1)
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to filter the first observation with type == "y" of each id, you can just use the basic `duplicated` function to do the job.

```
df1 <- df[!duplicated(df[, c("id", "type")]), ] %>% filter(type == "y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using `by` and `which.max`.

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$id, \(x) x[1:which.max(x$type == 'y'), ]))
#      id type
# 1.1   1    x
# 1.2   1    x
# 1.3   1    y
# 2.5   2    x
# 2.6   2    x
# 2.7   2    x
# 2.8   2    y
# 3.10  3    x
# 3.11  3    x
# 3.12  3    x
# 3.13  3    x
# 3.14  3    y
```